# AmazonMQ (ActiveMQ on AWS) platform scalability

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I've used AMQ for years standalone and it can be very efficient for many messaging scenarios when properly configured.  We are looking to use the new 
[AmazonMQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/), but are concerned about limitations of the [current configuration options](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/pricing/)

- only active/standby (no network of brokers)
- 200GB max message store
- max instance size of mq.m4.large (2 vCPUs, 8GB)?

Does anyone have any information about the roadmap to enhance this going forward?

1. support for network of brokers (horizontal scaling)?
2. larger instance support (vertical scaling)?